# wordpress: How can I display multiple pages on one page?

Tags: wordpress

Let's say I have three different pages, page1, page2, and page3.

I want page1 and page2 to display on my static front page. Do I restrict the loop to only pull page1 and page2, or do I need to start the loop, test for name="page1" or something like that, and then print?
Thanks!
-Joe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would skip the loop and simply use `get_page($id)` as described here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page

All you need to know is the ID's of your pages, and you can pull them one at a time anywhere you want.

Comment: If I wanted to apply the template I specified in Wordpress on each of these pages?

Comment: This approach is now deprecated

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this question also, but `get_page` has now been deprecated. Can anyone recommend an alternative, please?

Comment: You now have to use `get_post` instead as specified here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could do it. This code will work if you have all the pages that you want to be displayed under one parent. In this case, I was putting pages under the home page (p.post_parent = 2).

```
if ($post->post_type == 'page') {                    

    $pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT p.ID, p.post_name, p.post_title, p.post_parent, pm.meta_value FROM $wpdb->posts AS p LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pm ON pm.post_id=p.ID AND pm.meta_key='wp_menu_nav' LEFT JOIN $wpdb->posts AS P ON P.ID=p.post_parent WHERE p.post_parent = 2 AND p.post_type='page' AND p.post_status='publish' ORDER BY p.menu_order ASC"); 

    if ($wpdb->num_rows > 0) {                          

        foreach($pages as $page) {

            //echo $page->ID . "<br>";
            $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'post_type'=> 'page', 'include' => $page->ID, 'post_status' => 'published' );

            $myposts = get_posts($args);

            foreach($myposts as $mypost) {
                setup_postdata($mypost);
                echo the_content();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Typically it is not a good idea to use raw SQL queries if you can avoid it. There are a lot of built in ways to access an arbitrary  number of pages with WordPress. get_page() or modifying the query at 'pre_get_posts' would work well.

Comment: You mean the WordPress functions that make multiple unnecessary calls and connections to the database?

How about actually giving some code samples rather than referring to some functions that anyone can look up, which helps nobody? What I offered was a real solution that works ;-)