# wordpress expand collapse pages

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am given a developing CMS site in wordpress.I am learning now html,css,php,jquery,ajax and ofcourse doing research on wordpress..

so my site should some what look like this

[image]

now in this the

There is only one page that is displayed ...**main page**

and i have 3 pages(about,home,people) created in wordpress (Wordpress--->Pages---->new page--->write content)

1)In main page as shown in image i want 3 panels (About,Home,People) all of which are collapsed when **main page** page is opened

2)but once clicked on Home it should expand the home panel and display the page contents there itself without reloading the page.And other panels should collapse at the same time.

3)When Clicked on menu bar item  (About or any other) The Panel with same name should expand..

If there are any sites that people know that will somehow answer my queries, please pass them on.

**EDIT1**

I downloaded the jquery examples from site http://jqueryui.com/download

i want the tabs as in collapsible.html example

now the below code is the page.php

```
      <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); // added this line  16-7-2012
?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');          ?>/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/query.ui.accordion.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>/js/demos.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');  ?>/js/jquery.ui.all.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />



<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true
    });
});
</script>


   <?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="content">

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php $page_id=1332;?>
<?php get_page( $page_id ) ?> 

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <?php the_content('Read more'); ?>



    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>

<?php else : ?>

    <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
    <p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/searchform.php"); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

 <?php if (is_single()) comments_template(); ?>

</div>

 <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

as it loads all the pages..
In WP pages(content section) i have written the html code given in jquery examples i.e the below code:

```
  <div id="accordion">
  <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
   <div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
</div>
  <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
</div>
  <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
    <ul>
        <li>List item one</li>
        <li>List item two</li>
        <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>
<div>
    <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est. </p><p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
</div>
```

but its displayed as plain textt with no accordion tabs

[image]

**EDIT2**

```
    function{
  $(function() {
      $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true
      });
  })};
```

**EDIT3**

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){   
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the collapsible part, you could use the jquery ui accordion.:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

The simplest way would be to do it w/o ajax and just render all your pages in the main page.
see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page and [wordpress: How can I display multiple pages on one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309382/wordpress-how-can-i-display-multiple-pages-on-one-page)

There for you'll just need to modify the `index.php` file in your theme.

--

You could also load the pages content via ajax as described here:
[jQuery Accordion and loading content through AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646415/jquery-accordion-and-loading-content-through-ajax)

For that you'll also need to modify the `page.php` template to show just the content, with no header / footer.

Comment: Thanks Max Gherkins..Loading multiple  pages now working fine...

but the accordion tabs not working ..i tried the code from the link you provided ..but its not getting collapsed ...

Comment: did you include all the necessary JS and CSS files http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started ?

Comment: WP templates are just HTML with some mixed in PHP-code end therefor having the .php suffix. You should be able to use any HTML code from the examples in Wordpress templates.

Comment: try wrapping your function function, where you init the accordion into `$(document).ready(function(){ /* here */ });`

Comment: otherwise the #accordion elements won't be rendered, yet

Comment: hey thanks..
i did the changes but still doesnt work...:(

i have edited the question..

Comment: in your edit you have `function{` before your call, this might cause errors... do you get any errors on the javascript console? (firefox w/ firebug/chrome etc.)?

Comment: no i dont get any errors.. in firefox..
but how i should write it?That is not the correct way??

Comment: i think you have wrapped it in one too many function... http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13990/discussion-between-pradnya-and-max-gherkins)